# gdm3 opens new window when logging in

Tags: gnome

This is ubuntu server 20.04 with ubuntu-desktop installed. What is happening is on startup, the login screen appears on screen ctrl-alt-f1 (as expected). When I log in, it opens a new session on ctrl-alt-f2, and another login screen on ctrl-alt-f1. The effect of this is that if I choose power off in my gnome session, it leaves me on ctrl-alt-f2, and I don't see the shutdown text, just a black screen. Is this normal behavior, or did I mess something up somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behaviour. Where formally a graphical session was running on `tty7`, since quite a few versions the login manager runs on `tty1` and the user's desktop on `tty2`.

Normal behaviour is that the system shuts fully down when the user selects "Shut down", but since yours is configured as a server...

Comment: Thanks. I was curious about why I didn't see the shutdown text. On this system anyway, choosing power off from the desktop does shut it down completely. Had to install from the server image because this is a raspberry pi, and there is no desktop image for arm64.